# How to pause a loop to ask for input (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, cocoa, xcode, ipad, ipod

I have a fairly simple looped operation that checks for obvious errors and likely problems in a data structure. I won't go into detail about it. What I want to be able to do is pause the execution of this loop whenever an error is encountered so that I can ask the user what they want to do about that error, before continuing to check the remaining data.

Can anyone give any ideas about how best to do that?

-Ash

Comment: Is it being run on a thread? Or is it just getting called via a timer?

Answer (score 1):

Don't do long operations inside a loop in the UI run loop.  It presents a non-responsive UI to the user; and the OS may kill the app if it locks up for too long.

Break the loop into short callbacks (make the inside of each loop iteration a method), and exit each callback after maybe a fraction of a seconds worth of inner loop operations.

Or execute the loop as a task in a background thread, and use locks to stop the loop while waiting for messages from the foreground UI run loop about what to do for some loop state.

Comment: Thanks for the advice; in fact I have chosen the method of performing the loop in a background thread which will not cause this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This will stop your loop for 0.25 seconds, but it's not what you are looking to do. You need to reformulate your question first.

```
CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0.25, false);
```

Comment: Not quite what I need, but it *did* quite by coincidence lead me to the actual answer I was looking for, so thank you all the same :)

Comment: @Ash I am intrigued. Please share you solution with us.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like UIAlertView is what you are looking for:

[UIAlertView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html)

Comment: I'll be using that temporarily to present options to the user until I make my own alert class for better customisability, but in fact calling a UIAlertView doesn't pause the execution of the program at all. Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 0):

UIAlertView is asynch, so it won't pause the loop.

There are cleverer ways to write your loop, e.g. using blocks or completion handlers, but I'd suggest the EASIEST way is simply convert your code from:

```
-(void) method
{
...
for( int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
check_loop_item(i);
}
}
```

to:

```
int iCurrent, iEnd;

-(void) method
{
...
iCurrent = 0;
iEnd = 10;
[self doLoop];
}

-(void) doLoop
{
if( iCurrent >= iEnd )
return;

check_loop_item(iCurrent);
...
if( error )
{
// Popup a UIAlertView
}
else
{
iCurrent++;
[self doLoop];
}
```

...and in the callback method from UIAlertView, do:

```
-(void) callbackFromUIAlertView
{
iCurrent++;
[self doLoop];
}
```

...i.e. a loop that runs once at a time, and lets you arbitrarily stop / pause / resume it.